# how to add image from url in opencart 1.5.6

Tags: php, html, opencart

i have installed Opencart 1.5.6, i have uploaded all product from CSV. i have 30000 products.
with images urls. so i want add image from urls in my open-cart website. plz help me howz its possible. and where i change for this.

what i change in in what file and where.

```
<div class="left">
      <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a></div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($images) { ?>
      <div class="image-additional">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by adding images by urls? how are image links stored in your `product_image` table, full link or just path ?

Comment: i want use remote server image in my opencart website.  i have image     http://library.bevnetwork.com/labels/500/35683.jpg, http://library.bevnetwork.com/bottles/500/s_135403.jpg, any my website is https://shopchakra.com/

Comment: As for default OC the images need to be present in the site's filesystem under the `<ROOT>/images/data/` folder. Usually when You create a product and assign (I mean from already uploaded ones or when uploading a new at a step) image(s) to it the original image is stored as well as thumb and resized overview images are created. I think this should be handled within the importer - when importing a product from CSV, the original image should be downloaded from the remote server and treated as usual. If this is not possible then You'd need to change the product image loading in whole OpenCart...

Answer (score 0):

Simply Opencart uses the resize method to maintain the image size fetched from database which creates the cache image file and maintains its path,

/catalog/product/product.php you can see method

```
$this->data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
```

Here this method
`$this->model_tool_image->resize(image_path,width,height);`
 assigned to popup variable,
just remove this part and place with your full image path
like

```
$this->data['popup'] = $product_info['image'];

//you are using remote server image so full image path should be in product table
```

Here we are not using image resize method so you need to handle image size with css, in this way you can manage other images too.
Hope this helps